# how to fix Visual Studio installation is incomplete?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart

I have some problem with debug my app for running on windows
error:
Exception: Unable to find suitable Visual Studio toolchain. Please run `flutter doctor` for more details.
and when run flutter doctor the issue was :
[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 17.5.1) X The current Visual Studio installation is incomplete. Please reinstall Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

After an hour with reinstaling visual studio and modifying (Desktop development with C++) the problem fixed.